# Scarpy Installation Error. How to fix it?

Tags: python

I am trying to install Scrapy.

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'F:\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
>   sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ngotb8u1\Twisted\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ngotb8u1\Twisted\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rgt32hb0\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\Twisted' Check
>   the logs for full command output.

How to fix it? Python 3.8

Comment: try upgrading your `pip` version.. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Installing scrapy on Windows using `pip` is notably tricky. The current recommended way to get Scrapy on Windows is to use Anaconda/Miniconda and the `conda install scrapy` command from the anaconda prompt.

If you dont use conda then you can try issuing the `pip install scrapy` command in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio. 
If that doesnt work then manually download twisted from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
Choose the version and download it. 
then run the following

```
pip install <Twisted-18.7.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl>


pip install Scrapy
```

and if missing

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Its old but check out this video also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEK2kmmvIdw